# 403 Forbidden when using ANSIBLE login Cisco ACI

Tags: ansible, cisco

I'm learning ANSIBLE and try to manage CISCO ACI env.

Here is a Ubuntu that I installed Ansible to run the CISCO automations.

My playbook for manage CISCO ACI looks like below:

```yaml
---
- name: ANSIBLE-Script
  hosts: apic
  connection: local
  gather_facts: FALSE

  vars:
          apic_info: &apic_info
            host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
            username: admin
            password: C1sc0123!
            validate_certs: FALSE

  tasks:
         - name: create tenant
           cisco.aci.aci_tenant:
                    <<: *apic_info
                    tenant: ansible
                    state: present
           delegate_to: localhost
~
```

When I execute playbook, the fault generated:
Ubuntu:~/ACI$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini playbook.yml

```
PLAY [ANSIBLE-Script] **********************************************************************************

TASK [create tenant] ***********************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.1.1 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Connection failed for https://localhost/api/aaaLogin.json. Request failed: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************
10.124.147.186             : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I guess that would be some local connection issue on Ubuntu or ANSIBLE env? Or ACI REST API side should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

zh

You are using ansible facts in the variable, may be that causing issue for connection.
host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
`host: "{{ ansible_host }}"`

replace line with

`host: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"`

The reason I'm asking this because in the ansible facts you can find the list with the following ad-hoc command:

````bash
controlplane $ ansible -m setup localhost |grep ansible_host
        "ansible_hostname": "controlplane",
        "ansible_hostnqn": "",```
````

Comment: After replace this, the fault issue was changed as well.
```
{"changed": false, "msg": "Connection failed for https://10.124.147.186/api/aaaLogin.json. Request failed: <urlopen error timed out>"}
```